# Using the compatible libraries in android

Tags: android, compatibility, actionbarsherlock

What is an ideal approach when developing apps using android 4.0 and making it work in android 2.3, I have already imported compatibility library and [Android Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html)? on my project?

Should I use the coding practices of 4.0 until my app is in shape before I apply compatibility  practices?

OR

I should apply the compatibility practices together with the project's progression (which is kinda hardcore.. for a beginner of the compatibility library like me )?

I would appreciate your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I may be a bit biased, but by using the Google support library, [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com), and [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) you are afforded all of the major new features introduced in Honeycomb to 99% of all devices that have access to the Play Store.

Having easy access to fragments, loaders, the action bar, and the new animation API on Android 2.1+ allows for you to focus on the actual content of your application rather than any API differences.

Answer (score 0):

Action Bar Sherlock is meant to replicate the Android 4.0 experience as closely as possible on legacy systems, so I suggest you use it in that spirit.  Try to develop clean Ice Cream Sandwich code, just keep an eye on whether ABS supports it.  Most of the time, it will.  If it doesn't, find another way.  Every time you finish coding up an Activity would probably be a good time to step back and do a quick Gingerbread sanity check.